# Chrome: unable to access the network

Tags: google-chrome

What does this message means? It appears only for some sites from time to time, i.e. **network** is accessible. Then what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: many folks about the internet suggest checking your firewall settings and allowing chrome. that indicates that the web resource in question is trying to call back to you out-of-band, rather than as a response within the existing http connection. some plugins may require it. Or it may just be that your ISP connection is flapping occasionally, and losing connectivity. is it always the same pages that do it?

Comment: I don't understand, what it means. If HTTP request sent, then it should (1) either no answer (2) or report some HTTP response. In former case Chrome should say "this page is not available". What does this specific message mean?

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned, there can be many causes.

Is is the same site(s) every time?
Is it the same time of day?
Is it at work or at home?
Does it only happen on Chrome? What about Internet Explorer, Safari, Firefox?
Have you added the website to the whitelist in the firewall as a test?
Is your browser up to date?

There are alot of reasons why you would not be able to access a site.

Another thing you can try if you have an Andriod device with Chrome is to put it the device on the same network (wi-fi) that the computer is on and see if the site works.

Comment: The question is why does Chrome report senseless message?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question. Frank Thomas is right, the Google support forums all point to the Chrome browser as most likely being blocked by the firewall or your anti-virus.  Try googling ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED, and you'll see that most recommendations are to ensure that chrome.exe is whitelisted in your firewall and the anti-virus software.